# jTDS 1.2.7 and SQL Server 2000 Default instance

Tags: java, android, sql-server, jtds

a very simple snippet:

```
private static final String mydriver="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";    

private static final String myurl="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/myDatabase";

private Connection myconn;

[stuff]

public int connect(final String username,final String password){

    try{
    Class.forName(mydriver);
    myconn=DriverManager.getConnection(myurl,username,password);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       return 1;
      } catch (SQLException e) {
       return 2;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Note please, a number of points:
   1. As a control, I have installed a very simple client called MSSQL Client by Pascal Nunes. It takes IP,DB,user,pwd and connects SUCCESSFULLY (without specifying port 1433). I have verified with Pascal himself, he is using jTDS 1.2.7, so I made sure my jTDS version was in line with his.
   2. I have tried a number of parameters and parameter combinations, but nothing seems to work
   3. I know neither the server nor the network can be responsible, since Pascal's app works
   4. Pascal's app has "Full Network Access" according to my Nexus 7. I have given my app:
android.permission.INTERNET in the manifest. I don't see any other permissions that might apply, but I'm new at this
   5. Otherwise, there must be jTDS parameters that need to be morphed away from their default. If so, damned if I can find 'em.

Any ideas?

Comment: The security model changed between SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005.  If you are using new network libraries, they are probably having issues.  Why the heck are you using 2000 when 2014 is getting released soon?  Did you look at the SQL Server error log or Windows application log of the database server for errors??

Comment: with all due respect, my point is: a free android app is communicating with my server given minimal information, and what should be a relatively simple code snippet is failing (additional note: Eclipse's SQL explorer works with an IDENTICAL url, both intranet (192.168. etc) and extranet. the tablet fails with the same string, but pascal makes it work with the same driver.

Comment: Searching the log files for errors is basic troubleshooting.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you still face this problem. Happened to find this question while searching for something else. But I believe I am the Pascal you mention and [MSSQL client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.nunes.mssqlclient) is the application you are referring to.  I will try to answer your question as best I can:

jtds doesn't require you to specify a port. 1433 is taken by default.

Building a connection string is [very well documented](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html) for jtds. This is how I build the connection string:

```
String properties = ";domain=" + domain + ";user=" + id + ";password=" + pass;
String conn = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + Server + "/" + Database + properties;
```

The app only needs network(android.permission.INTERNET) access.

Hope the answer helps you and others who come along.